# How to change data length parameter in maxima software?

Tags: maxima

I need to use maxima software to deal with data. I try to read data from a text file constructed as

```
1 2 3
11 22 33
ect.
```

Following comands allow for loading data sufficiently.

```
load(numericalio);
read_matrix("path to the file");
```

The problem arises when I apply them to a more realistic (larger) data set. In this case the message appears `Expression longer than allowed by the configuration setting`.
How to overcome this problem? I cannot see any option in configuration menu. I would be grateful for advice.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same error message today, at it seems to be related to the size of the output that wxMaxima receives from the Maxima executable.

If you wish to display the output regardless, you can change it in the configuration here:
`Edit`>`Configure`>`Worksheet`>`Show long expressions`

Note that showing a massive expression or amount of data may dramatically slow the program down, so consider hiding the output (use a `$` instead of a `;` at the end of your lines) if you don't need to visualize the data.

Comment: This was a help to me.